# not able to use selector to find an element of a page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm am trying to click a button in a page, and after 2 hours trying to do that, I felt that it was time to ask for help.

the code of the page that points to the button is as follows:

```
<div class="ui-pg-div"> == $0
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-calculator"></span>"CSV.    " == $0
</div>
```

the css selector is as follows:

```
#Pager_1822701482_left > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5) > div`
```

and the XPATH is as follows:

```
//*[@id="Pager_1822701482_left"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div
```

i have tried the following:

```
btn_csv = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ui-pg-div")
btn_csv = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#Pager_1822701482_left > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5) > div")
```

And tried several other combinations with class, name and some others that don't make any sense, but as i am new to coding, i was willing to try anything...

any help is appreciated, does anyone have any idea?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened when you tried the above locators? What error did you get?

Comment: it gives an error, stating that the selector was not found. I tried, time.sleep(10) so that the all page would load, but even then, it did not work...

Comment: Please post the actual error message. If the element wasn't found, then you need to investigate if the locator is correct, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you get to learn [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)!

to select that bad boy try this:

```
btn_csv = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="post-text"]')
btn_csv.click()
```

I had the same problem and so most of the time used something like

```
btn_csv = driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('div[class=\"post-text\"]')[0]')
btn_csv.click()
```

which for some reason worked

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i tried the code, and it doesn't give me an error, but the click just doesn't happens, it runs the rest of the code following, this line. do you have any other suggestion? i am reading the link that you sent in order to learn more about css selectors :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the button with text as **CSV.** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ui-pg-div > span.ui-icon.ui-icon-calculator").click()
```